# Updating Foreign Key Table in EF4.1 MVC3. Object is null on POST

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

When i use foreign keys in the entity framework the foreign key object is null when i do a POST.  I am using MVC3 and EF 4.1.  I have two tables, Product and Product Details.  I am exposing them using the HTML helpers in a Razor view.  When the GET happens, the product details are shown.  But when i do a form Submit and post to the server, the Product Details collection is null.  I lose all my changes.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

The Code (i shortened it because it is fairly lengthy):

Database:

```
Table Product
{
  int Id
  varchar Name
}

Table ProductDetails
{
  int id,
  int ProductId, <- foreign key SQL 2008 to Product Table
  varchar Details
}


View:
@model WebSite.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyLifeSaverStoreInfo";
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.ProductDetails.FirstOrDefault().Description)

Controller:
public ActionResult EditProduct(int productId)
{
  var Product = _productRepository.GetProduct(productId);
  return View(product);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(Product model)
{
   string name = model.Name; <- this update comes through
   string description = model.ProductDetails.FirstorDefault().Description;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: When you wrote this question didn't you consider important to post some of the code you have so far? If I was asking a question I would definitely have provided the code I have tried so far. It would be best if you could provide a full scenario (Model, Controller, View) allowing to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Instead of creating the "Product" entity on the POST EditProduct method, i use a Form Collection and then set each product detail according to that form collection and then save.  I don't understand why it doesn't work the first way.  I am manually updating the foreign reference.  Maybe i am missing something?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(int id, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var model = new MyLSstoreInfoViewModel{
                                  StoreCurrent = _profileRepository.GetProduct(Id)
                                          };
    var productDetails = model.Product.ProductDetails.Where(p => p.productId == id).Single();


            productDetaisl.Details = formCollection["details"];
            if (TryUpdateModel(model.StoreCurrent))
            {

                _profileRepository.Save();

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but maybe useful for someone in the future:

If you pass the primary key of the referenced child as a hidden input in the view, it will correctly resolve the child model in the action.